# How to add to an existing List value in a Map?

Tags: dart

I have the following Map from a JSON static file. I would like to add to the List that exists in the the Map already.

The below is an example of the Map.toString()

```
{'section': {'group1': {'name': 'bob', 'pets': ['dog', 'cat', 'hamster']}}}
```

I would like to add another pet to the existing pets list. I have attempted to use the below pattern based on a previous answer but it throws an error.

```
Map<String, dynamic> existingContent = json.decode(file.readAsStringSync());
List<dynamic> petList = existingContent['section']['group1']['pets'];
petList.add('peacock');
existingContent['section']['group1']['pets'] = petList.toList().toString();
```

> E/flutter (20787): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)]
>   Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on
>   null. E/flutter (20787): Receiver: null

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What line is giving you this error?

Comment: I actually just found an typo, this is working now.

Comment: Oh Ok Great!!!!!

Comment: Instead of `existingContent['section']['group1']['pets'] = petList.toList().toString();` you could just do `existingContent['section']['group1']['pets'] = petList;`. The 'pets' object is already a List (otherwise the assignment in line 2, to `petList` wouldn't work).